# IntelliJ - MySQL ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

So I'm trying to copy a remote database into my local database using IntelliJ and MySQL, and I've already obtained the remote database's data. The problem comes when I try to establish a connection with MySQL:

```
public void copyDatabase(Info info){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Connection");
            localConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lsmotor_local_oltp", user, password);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Problem while trying to connect to local database");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //TODO: Copy Info into local database
}
```

And it keeps giving me this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection` which is what's printed in the second catch.

I already have the mysql-connector-java-8.0.172 library on my Project Structure, and as shown in the code I wish to connect with the lsmotor_local_oltp database, that I already created and executed its code.
I've checked around but most posts say the solution is having the mysql-connector library, which I already have.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: given that you already included the required mysql jdbc driver library, you should check for proper configuration parameters. Please check the parameters for your respective version of your MySQL database and driver and ensure that they are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-java-connection.php

You likely have not included the mysql JDBC connector library on the classpath. Once you have it you should be able to run code like the one in the example.

```java
   Class.forName ("com.MySQL.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();   <<< this line is the one you want (or something similar)
   String userName = "root";
   String password = "pqrs123";
   String url = "jdbc:MySQL://localhost/sakila";        
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
   System.out.println ("\nDatabase Connection Established...");
```

Comment: The problem is that I have used the `forName("com.MySQL.jdbc.Driver")` before, and it said that it was deprecated (I am using Java Version 11.0.2): **Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.**
And when I check File -> Project Structure -> Modules it shows the mysql-connector there with the box checked. I will try to build it again just in case.
Thanks for your reply regardless!

Answer (score 0):

You have the exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException because the class com.mysql.jdbc.Connection doesn't exist. If you want to connect to your database you can use [this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)

Comment: Oh my mistake there, I was using Driver but since it kept showing **Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.** I stopped using it.
In case it's deprecated, what can be used instead? 
Thanks by the way for your response!

Comment: the tutotrial that I linked works with the new Driver 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. You just have to change the name in the method Class.forName

Comment: Yes it worked thank you a lot! Now it says something about the server timezone on the sqlexception, which means I probably need to change the server time of mysql server.

Comment: You can change you server's Timezone or you can add this to the database url "**?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone={your time zone}**"

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters/setup in your properties file or something, related to mysql JDBC driver

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I found out in my case i need to use "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" but now the **"Problem while trying to connect to local database"** message pops out, which means now is a SQLException and not a ClassNotFoundException.